# Is svg.js capable of path morphing animation

Tags: svg.js, svg-morphing

I've written a tool for creating animated svgs using path morphing.  Currently, my tools rely on just building the  code out of strings, but I was interested in transitioning to the svg.js library.  I've kind of run into a roadblock with the path morphing piece though, i.e. to create something like this

http://letmespellitoutforyou.com/samples/svg/anim_morph.svg

I don't see anything in the svg.js docs concerning animation

http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#animating-elements

that talk about animating the 'd' attribute and supplying it with to= and from= parameters.  Can someone tell me if this is supported, how I might do it, and if it's not, is it possible to just compose the  element myself and add it to an svg.js object?

Comment: I'm working on path morphing at the moment and it will be one of the requirements to release `1.0.0`.

Comment: @wout great script but is it ok now to make this with 1.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Old questions deserve an answer, too.

Pathmorphing was finally added to svg.js as plugin.
You can get it here: [svg.pathmorphing.js](https://github.com/Fuzzyma/svg.pathmorphing.js).

Please note that it is currently not possible to morph arcs into eachother.
Everything else works very well.